# How to benchmark Rust performance?

Tags: performance, rust, benchmarking

I understand this question could be duplicate from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13322479/benchmarking-programs-in-rust)

But I suppose the mentioned this question could be out of date.

Is there any new approach that is recommended by the official documentation?

Comment: The accepted answer is marked as out of date, but there are other (very complete) answers there.

Comment: It would be good to give an example of the code you would like to benchmark.  You could even try one of the techniques described in the linked question and ask if there is a better way -- specifically what it is about the solution that you find undesirable.